# QGIS: Aligning elements in the second column in the legend

Tags: qgis, legend

I am not able to create a legend in such a way that the legend elements from the second column are below its title, i.e. the element "222" is at the same height as "111". How to separate the title of the legend from its elements?[image: legend]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My suggestion would be to disable 'Auto Update' for the Legend and set the layer name in the legend to 'Hidden'. This will align the symbols.

1. Disable 'Auto update' and right-click the layer name in the Legend Items list.

[image]

2. Check 'Hidden' in the context menu to hide the layer name from the legend.

[image]

This will align the symbols

[image]

3. Use a Label item for the legend title

[image]

You could either:

- copy-paste the layer name directly into the label
- make the label text dynamic by using an expression such as this:

```
layer_property( 
    map_get(
        item_variables('Legend'),      -- the name of the RENAMED legend item
        'layer_ids')[0],               -- the id of the first layer in the legend
    'name'                             -- get the 'name' property of the layer using its id     
)
```

###### Note:

For the expression to recognise the Legend item, it must be must be renamed (by clicking on it in the Layout Items pane)

[image]

---

###### Modified expressions to include feature count

###### Count all features in the layer

```
with_variable(                          -- make a variable of the (first) layer in the legent
    'legend_layer',
    map_get(
        item_variables('Legend'),       -- the name of the RENAMED legend item
        'layer_ids'
    )[0],

    layer_property( 
        @legend_layer,                  -- the id of the first layer in the legend
        'name'                          -- get the 'name' property of the layer using its id     
    )  || 
    
    ' [' ||
    layer_property(                     -- get the feature count and append to layer name
        @legend_layer,
        'feature_count'
    ) || ']'                            -- enclose in square brackets to emulate default formatting
)
```

###### Count features that intersect the specified map extent

```
with_variable(                          -- make a variable of the (first) layer in the legend
    'legend_layer',
    map_get(
        item_variables('Legend'),       -- the name of the RENAMED legend item
        'layer_ids'
    )[0],

    layer_property( 
        @legend_layer,                  -- the id of the first layer in the legend
        'name'                          -- get the 'name' property of the layer using its id     
    )  || 
    
    ' [' ||
    num_geometries(                     -- count intersecting features
        intersection(                   -- get features that intersect with the map extent
            aggregate(                  -- collect all features in the 'legend_layer'
                @legend_layer,
                'collect',
                $geometry
            ), 
            map_get(                    -- get the 'Map 1' extent as a geometry object
                item_variables('Map 1'),
                'map_extent'
            )
        )
    )
     || ']'                            -- enclose in square brackets to emulate the default formatting
)
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks

Comment: I noticed you had the feature count visible after the name of your legend layer. I added two more expressions to include the feature count.